# Algebraic problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Am not sure about the title for this problem. Anyone can edit otherwise

In a test,a professor awards 5  marks for every question a student gets right and deducts 2 marks for a wrong answer.In that test, a certain student got 90%.if there were 25 questions,how many questions did the student fail?

The method I used was:
Let the questions the student got Right be X and wrong y
Hence,  x+y = 25-----------eqn 1.
Total marks for the test is;
25x5= 125 marks
Hence,  5x +2y = 125----------eqn 2.
I solved the two eqns but I doubt whether the logic is correct.

Comment: I think your second equation should be $5x-2y=90$ (assuming student got $90$ points, not $90$%)

Comment: if the certain student got 90% then the  number of correct answers is not an integer, it should be 90 points, indeed.

Comment: @Vasya Thanks for your concern. Why should we not convert the 90%into marks

Comment: @AlvinLepik Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Let }\begin{aligned}\text{Right Answers}&: x\\ \text{Wrong Answers} &:y\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{cases}x+y=25\\ 5x-2y=90\end{cases}$$

Can you proceed?